# matplotlib: number at top of y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a really dumb question. I am plotting a function using pyplot. In addition to the normal y-axis ticks, there is a number (an arithmetic expression, actually) that appears at the top of the y-axis. What is this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def f(a, b, Kx):
    return a / (a**2 + (1 + Kx)**(2*b))
Kx = np.logspace(-6, -4)
plt.plot(Kx, f(10, 0.001, Kx))
```

[image: the plot produced by the above code]